# Multiple calls to getopts in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, getopts

When this script is called

`test.sh -a 1 -b 2 -c 3`

output is :
`-a 1 -b 2
1`

I was expecting `parseRemainingArgs` to parse and print all arguments.
As you can see all the arguments are passed properly to `parseRemainingArgs` as seen in first line of output, but it parses only the first argument.

I set the OPTIND as well but that also didn't help.

Need help in identifying what is wrong with this and how to fix that.

Tried all available answers which google provides but none of them solves this problem.

```
#!/bin/sh
parseRemainingArgs()
{
    echo $@
    OPTIND=1
    while getopts :ha:b:c: o;
    do
        case "$o" in
                h) echo "Print help";;
                a) FIRST_ARG="$OPTARG";;
                b) SECOND_ARG="$OPTARG";;
                c) THIRD_ARG="$OPTARG";;
                \?) ;;
        esac
    done
    echo $FIRST_ARG $SECOND_ARG $THIRD_ARG
}

parseArgs()
{
    AllArgs=$@
    while getopts :ht: o;
    do
        case "$o" in
                t) TARGET="$OPTARG";;
                h) HELP="yes";;
                \?) ;;
        esac
    done
    shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
    parseRemainingArgs $AllArgs
}

parseArgs $@
```

Comment: Tested after removing shift. No luck. Result is same.

Comment: When using `getopts`, you do a single `shift $(($OPTIND - 1))` after the loop and you do not do shifts during the loop.  Those shifts will throw things asked.  I'm leery of your use of `$@` without the double quotes.  Your remaining arguments function accepts `habc` according to the `getopts` call but processes `hack` according to the `case`; this seems like a hack.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have corrected the errors which you pointed out. Now it is working only in case when there is not argument matches in `parseArgs` function. In this case `parseAnotherArgs` is able to parse all arguments correctly. But when there is a match found in the arguments in `parseArgs` function; second function `parseAnotherArgs` fails to parse arguments. Thats weired to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Revised example command line

[Chhaba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2042813/chhaba) [observed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33515668/multiple-calls-to-getopts-in-bash/33526535?noredirect=1#comment54897392_33526535):

> To get the problem can you please test your script with the following arguments
>
> ```
> gomod.sh -t a -a 1 -b 2 -c 3
> ```
>
> In this case `-t` will match in `parseArgs` but `parseRemainingArgs` will fail to parse the remaining args. It works great when `-t` or `-h` is not given which matches in `parseArgs`.

OK; that's what I'd expect from the script I used (see the script below in the "'Cannot reproduce' response" section — it is a mild extension of what's in the question).  From `bash`, I get:

```
$ bash gomod.sh -t a -a 1 -b 2 -c 3
Initial arguments: -t a -a 1 -b 2 -c 3
Doing nothing
OPTIND = 4
Residual arguments: 1 -b 2 -c 3
Parsing Remaining: -t a -a 1 -b 2 -c 3
Ignoring error
a1: a2: a3
$
```

It's a consequence of you setting `AllArgs` at the start of `parseArgs`.  It doesn't change as you parse the arguments in `"$@"` in `parseArgs`, so you pass the original argument list to `parseRemainingArgs`, as shown in the diagnostic output.  In `parseRemainingArgs`, `-t` is not an option, so the loop returns an error on the `-t` (hence `Ignoring error`), and then exits because `a` is not an option.

You can get more output from:

```
$ bash gomod.sh -t -a 1 -b 2 -c 3
Initial arguments: -t -a 1 -b 2 -c 3
OPTIND = 3
Residual arguments: 1 -b 2 -c 3
Parsing Remaining: -t -a 1 -b 2 -c 3
Ignoring error
a1: 1 a2: 2 a3 3
$
```

It ignores the `-t` error in `parseRemainingArgs` and then processes each of `-a`, `-b` and `-c` with the corresponding argument.

Alternatively, you could modify the script, replacing the invocation of `parseRemainingArgs` with:

```
parseRemainingArgs "$@"
```

You can then run it like this, for example, and get the output shown:

```
$ bash gomod.sh -t antelope -- -a 1 -b 22 -c 333
Initial arguments: -t antelope -- -a 1 -b 22 -c 333
OPTIND = 4
Residual arguments: -a 1 -b 22 -c 333
Parsing Remaining: -a 1 -b 22 -c 333
a1: 1 a2: 22 a3 333
$
```

Note that replacing the `--` with nothing, or with `abelone` (or any other non-option) does not work as you'd want.

You could still add a lot more debugging to make it easier to understand, or run it under `bash -x`.

#### 'Cannot reproduce' response

I'm not sure what your problem is any more.  I've run a slightly modified version of your script — more diagnostics and using back-quotes and `expr` to calculate the shift (because some of the shells I tested with don't support the `$((…))` arithmetic notation).  The code was:

```
#!/bin/sh
parseRemainingArgs()
{
    echo "Parsing Remaining:" "$@"
    OPTIND=1
    while getopts :ha:b:c: o
    do
        case "$o" in
                h) echo "Print help";;
                a) FIRST_ARG="$OPTARG";;
                b) SECOND_ARG="$OPTARG";;
                c) THIRD_ARG="$OPTARG";;
                \?) echo "Ignoring error";;
        esac
    done
    echo a1: $FIRST_ARG a2: $SECOND_ARG a3 $THIRD_ARG
}

parseArgs()
{
    AllArgs=$@
    echo "Initial arguments:" "$@"
    while getopts :ht: o
    do
        case "$o" in
                t) TARGET="$OPTARG";;
                h) HELP="yes";;
                \?) echo "Doing nothing";;
        esac
    done
    #shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
    echo "OPTIND = $OPTIND"
    shift `expr $OPTIND - 1`
    echo "Residual arguments:" "$@"
    parseRemainingArgs $AllArgs
}

parseArgs "$@"
```

The shells tested were:

- `sh` — a link to `bash`
- `bash`
- `dash`
- `ksh` — Korn shell
- `zsh`
- `hsh` — Heirloom shell (close to Bourne shell)
- `svr4-sh` — Unix System V Release 4 (slightly souped up Bourne shell)

Of these, `hsh` and `svr4-sh` did not accept `shift $(($OPTIND - 1))`.  I'm slightly surprised the Heirloom shell recognizes `getopts` at all.

The script was called `gomod.sh`, and the output I got was:

```
$ for shell in sh bash dash ksh zsh hsh svr4-sh
> do
>     boxecho $shell
>     $shell gomod.sh -a 1 -b 2 -c 3
>     echo
> done
********
** sh **
********
Initial arguments: -a 1 -b 2 -c 3
Doing nothing
OPTIND = 2
Residual arguments: 1 -b 2 -c 3
Parsing Remaining: -a 1 -b 2 -c 3
a1: 1 a2: 2 a3 3

**********
** bash **
**********
Initial arguments: -a 1 -b 2 -c 3
Doing nothing
OPTIND = 2
Residual arguments: 1 -b 2 -c 3
Parsing Remaining: -a 1 -b 2 -c 3
a1: 1 a2: 2 a3 3

**********
** dash **
**********
Initial arguments: -a 1 -b 2 -c 3
Doing nothing
OPTIND = 2
Residual arguments: 1 -b 2 -c 3
Parsing Remaining: -a 1 -b 2 -c 3
a1: 1 a2: 2 a3 3

*********
** ksh **
*********
Initial arguments: -a 1 -b 2 -c 3
Doing nothing
OPTIND = 2
Residual arguments: 1 -b 2 -c 3
Parsing Remaining: -a 1 -b 2 -c 3
a1: 1 a2: 2 a3 3

*********
** zsh **
*********
Initial arguments: -a 1 -b 2 -c 3
Doing nothing
OPTIND = 2
Residual arguments: 1 -b 2 -c 3
Parsing Remaining: -a 1 -b 2 -c 3
a1:  1 -b 2 -c 3 a2: a3

*********
** hsh **
*********
Initial arguments: -a 1 -b 2 -c 3
Doing nothing
OPTIND = 2
Residual arguments: 1 -b 2 -c 3
Parsing Remaining: -a 1 -b 2 -c 3
a1: 1 a2: 2 a3 3

*************
** svr4-sh **
*************
Initial arguments: -a 1 -b 2 -c 3
Doing nothing
OPTIND = 2
Residual arguments: 1 -b 2 -c 3
Parsing Remaining: -a 1 -b 2 -c 3
a1: 1 a2: 2 a3 3

$
```

`boxecho` is a trivial script that echoes its arguments inside a box of stars:

```
echo "** $@ **" | sed -e h -e 's/./*/g' -e p -e x -e p -e x
```

I hadn't modified it since 1998; I don't often have a subdirectory `s` with a subdirectory inside that contains a file `g`, so the absence of quotes around the `s/./*/g` hadn't ever bit me, but I've fixed the script above (and in my `bin` directory).  There are other ways of writing the `sed` too; this does, however, work.

It is worth noting that the use of `getopts` in the `parseRemainingArgs` function works with the full set of arguments originally passed to the command, despite the implication that it is working on 'the remaining arguments'.  You'd pass `"$@"` to the function if it were to process the as yet unprocessed arguments.  It would also run into 'end of arguments' immediately unless you have a GNU `getopts` functionality without POSIXLY_CORRECT set in the environment since the first such argument would be `1` which is not an option and would terminate the `getopts` processing.

Comment: appreciate your efforts to to test it. To get the problem can you please test your script with the following arguments `gomod.sh -t a -a 1 -b 2 -c 3`. In this case `-t` will match in `parseArgs` but `parseRemainingArgs` will fail to parse the remaining args. It works great when `-t` or `-h` is not given which matches in `parseArgs`

Comment: Thank you @Jonathan Leffler for the wonderful explanation. This helped me in understanding how getopts works.